# Did LIGO detect dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, ligo

Which is the title of [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00464) They claim that:

> We consider the possibility that the black-hole (BH) binary detected
>   by LIGO may be a signature of dark matter. Interestingly enough, there
>   remains a window for masses 10M⊙≲Mbh≲100M⊙ where primordial black
>   holes (PBHs) may constitute the dark matter. If two BHs in a galactic
>   halo pass sufficiently close, they can radiate enough energy in
>   gravitational waves to become gravitationally bound. The bound BHs
>   will then rapidly spiral inward due to emission of gravitational
>   radiation and ultimately merge. Uncertainties in the rate for such
>   events arise from our imprecise knowledge of the phase-space structure
>   of galactic halos on the smallest scales. Still, reasonable estimates
>   span a range that overlaps the 2−53 Gpc−3 yr−1 rate estimated from
>   GW150914, thus raising the possibility that LIGO has detected PBH dark
>   matter.

Has this explanation for dark matter in this mass range been explored previously?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? If you're asking "Did LIGO detect dark matter?" the answer is no it detected two black holes. If you're asking whether black holes in the size range you mention could be the missing 25% of matter then I don't think we can tell at the moment.

Comment: @JohnRennie I suppose I am asking whether DM=BH is a real possibility given the (admittedly limited) figures they quote

Comment: @DirkBruere it is a hypothesis for what the  dark matter is, see MACHOs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_compact_halo_object .

Comment: @annav Yes, but does the LIGO results give credence to the hypothesis. other than not being a disproof?

Comment: @DirkBruere no, it is no extra evidence for the MACHO hypothesis. Just that the signal is consistent with high probability of being from the merging of two black holes of the respective masses. The masses are within the limits, so there is no inconsistency , but to validation either

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational micro-lensing has already put a non-trivial limit on the total mass density due to small-to medium sized black holes, but does not so far put one on heavy stellar-mass black holes.

Over time, the accumulated data of the (several) gravitational wave detectors may eventually put a limit on the high-mass MACHO contribution to the total mass density, but one observation does nothing in that direction.

The authors of the preprint have jumped the gun.